# Как правильно создавать Java EE приложения (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee

Разбираюсь с сервлетами. Подскажите как правильно создавать java ee проекты используя при этом maven.

Когда я создаю проект в Intellij IDEA, то выбираю maven, соответственно IDEA выберает платформу Java SE. Когда я использую класс HttpServlets он мигает красным (и это логично, ведь платформа SE), если я заимпотрирую

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
```

то идея подсветит слово servlet красным и предложит мне Add Java EE 6 JARs to module dependencies.

Обьясните пожалуйста как правильно поменять платформу на Java EE

Comment: Вам необходимо добавить зависимость в мавен, тут описан пример - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как сервлеты это отдельная спецификация он не включен Java SE. Вам надо добавить в pom.xml таким обзором мавен скачает зависимость.

```
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[Тут](https://github.com/nixwins/servlet-fast-run) можешь посмотреть проект для IDEA Community Edition. Настройка сервлета + томкат

Comment: Спасибо большое, я уже так делал но видимо криво (Сейчас все работает)
ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо